# android get shared text file from files

Tags: java, android, android-intent

im trying to get a text files contents. it is a file shared from the files browser ive narrowed it down to its a bundle that i can get from getextras.

but how do i get the data inside. the functions for retrieving require a key? i didn't create the intent. All the examples show both the send and receive therefore don't answer the question about what the key is.

```
intent.getExtras()
```

Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] typ=text/plain flg=0x1b080001 cmp=com.psymblyb.noter/.MainActivity clip={text/plain U:content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fsample.txt} (has extras)

```
intent.getExtras().toString()
```

Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=416]

Comment: intent.getData().toString().

Answer (score 0):

getdata was null too

i found it in:
intent.getClipData().getItemAt(0).coerceToText(this).toString();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).